# Magento PHP Fatal error when running cron.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

When I'm running cron.php for a Magento webshop, I see the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object
>   in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php on line 86

It is a Magento 1.6.2 webshop.

This is line 86:

```
$product    = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
```

This is the function, where the error arises:

```
public function processFrontFinalPrice($observer)
{
    $product    = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $pId        = $product->getId();
    $storeId    = $product->getStoreId();

    if ($observer->hasDate()) {
        $date = $observer->getEvent()->getDate();
    } else {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($storeId);
    }

    if ($observer->hasWebsiteId()) {
        $wId = $observer->getEvent()->getWebsiteId();
    } else {
        $wId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
    }

    if ($observer->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
        $gId = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerGroupId();
    } elseif ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
        $gId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    }

    $key = "$date|$wId|$gId|$pId";
    if (!isset($this->_rulePrices[$key])) {
        $rulePrice = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')
            ->getRulePrice($date, $wId, $gId, $pId);
        $this->_rulePrices[$key] = $rulePrice;
    }
    if ($this->_rulePrices[$key]!==false) {
        $finalPrice = min($product->getData('final_price'), $this->_rulePrices[$key]);
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

No modification are made in the core code of Magento

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace in `exception.log`?

Comment: Its seems like you try to calculating final price..And I saw issue on price event..Please check this out..

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

and

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=10777
I am not sure about this..But this may be..

Comment: Do you have any catalog price rules setup in the admin?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the exception.log. Yes there are catalog price rules setup in admin.

Comment: When I disable the catalog price rules, it's working correctly, no errors are shown.

Answer (score 0):

What event are you trying to catch?

Anyway i use that: `$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();`
It seems to work.

Comment: I'm not sure which event it's trying to catch. It's a core Magento file. I think the event is the catalog rule.

I don't understand what you mean with "Anyway I use that"